# Subsets of an ordered round table of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

The problem reads:

*Let the integers $1,2,\dots,n$ be arranged consecutively around a circle, and let $g(n)$ be the number of ways of choosing a subset, no two consecutive on the circle.*

In a previous exercise, I have the same problem but with the numbers arranged in a line. The answer to this previous problem is $f(n)=F_{n+2}$, where $F$ is a Fibonacci number.

So I have two cases:

1. $n$ is not counted in the $g(n-1)$ subsets, in which case, the number of subsets it's just $F_{n-1+2} = F_{n+1}$. (In other words, taking away $n$ I can arrange the remaining numbers on the line and then just close it in a necklace. No problem here I guess.
2. Suppose $n$ is counted **in** the subsets. So I have to take away the $1$ and the $n-1$ and then do the arrangement with $\lbrace 2,3,\dots,n-1,n\rbrace$. In this case I have $n-2$ objects which I can arrange on the line and then form a necklace, I would have $F_{n-2+2}$ ways to do so. **However**, my book says it should be $F_{n-1}$ ways for this case. Am I misisng something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be a subset containing $n$; then $S\setminus\{n\}$ can be any subset of the linear array $\{2,\ldots,n-2\}$, and there are $F_{\big((n-2)-1\big)+2}=F_{n-1}$ of those.

That is, you need to remove all three of the elements $n-1,n$, and $1$ from consideration and look at subsets of the remaining $n-3$ elements that have no adjacent elements in the linear arrangement.

Comment: Question, why I cannot include $n$ with the other $\lbrace 2,\dots,n-2\rbrace$?

Comment: @user2820579: You know that $n\in S$, so you’re interested only in the possibilities for $S\setminus\{n\}$. If you include $n$ with the others, any subset of that collection that contains $n$ is being counted twice.